# From the Land Of Wonders

Tags: wordplay, rebus

Can you work out what famous phrase is this?

> Fourteen years of jail, Alice.
>   wards
>   You are guilty, Alice.

Comment: is this a 'Bob' question?

Comment: Bob is lonely. Alice has been sent to jail afterall. xD

Comment: The first two lines could be "prison+wards" = "PRESS ONWARDS".

Comment: Can you forgive her?

Comment: Good point @Gamow.  That would also imply that the last line is a verdict, but I can't match it to your idea.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is

> "Sentence first -- verdict afterwards!" - [the Queen](https://ebooks.adelaide.edu.au/c/carroll/lewis/alice/chapter12.html)

Comment: Um, wow. I came across this phrase a LOT in my research but was so busy trying to figure out what "wards" could refer to that I didn't even think of it that way. :B

Comment: Oh my.  This is a good answer!

Comment: This is probably it. I was thinking the reference to Wonderland was to throw people onto the wrong track, but this fits too perfectly.

Comment: The reference to Wonderland could fit if that is a quote from the (Bloody Red) Queen.

Comment: It's definitely a direct quote from the Queen from Alice in Wonderland. My attribution to "the Queen" is a link to the chapter in which the line occurs. The chapter was the closest I could get, couldn't get directly to the line, sorry.

Comment: @DylanCristy Wonderful !

Answer (score 0):

Is it

> Alice Is Taught to Grow Upwards, Towards the Light